# Prevent partial argument matching

Tags: r

I have an R function:

```
myFunc <- function(x, base='') {
}
```

I am now extending the function, allowing a set of arbitrary extra arguments:

```
myFunc <- function(x, base='', ...) {
}
```

**How may I disable partial argument matching on the `base` parameter?** I cannot put the `...` before `base=''` because I'd like to maintain backwards compatibility of the function (it is often called as `myFunction('somevalue', 'someothervalue')` without `base` being explicitly named).

I got stung by calling my function like so:

```
myFunc(x, b='foo')
```

I *want* this to mean `base='', b='foo'`, but R uses partial matching and assumes `base='foo'`.

Is there some code I can insert in `myFunc` to determine what argument names were passed in and only match the *exact* "base" to the `base` parameter, otherwise grouping it in as part of the `...`?

Comment: You could perhaps use `sys.call()`, and check from there how the function was called.

Comment: How about calling the new API `myFunc2`, and keeping the old one (`myFunc`) exactly as it is for backwards compatibility (but changing the implementation to be a simple wrapper around `myFunc2`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
myFunc <- function(x, .BASE = '', ..., base = .BASE) {
    base
}

## Takes fully matching named arguments       
myFunc(x = "somevalue", base = "someothervalue")
# [1] "someothervalue"

## Positional matching works
myFunc("somevalue", "someothervalue")
# [1] "someothervalue"

## Partial matching _doesn't_ work, as desired
myFunc("somevalue", b="someothervalue")
# [1] ""
```

Comment: I mentioned in the question already that I didn't want to move the `...` before `base` for backwards compatibility. Leaning towards @Hemmo's suggestion, although suspect I may end up using @NPE's.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee I saw that, which is why this addresses the one backwards compatibility issue that you raised (i.e. that users will rely on positional matching to pass supplied values to the `base` argument).

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't see the `.BASE` bit! I would do this for each optional argument I had, right?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee -- Yeah, you'd do this each argument for which you want the possibility of positional matching, but **do not** want partial matching of names.

Comment: Well, this does certainly answer my question and is pretty neat. I might just end up using @NPE's suggestion though - it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to simply set some R [options](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/options.html). In particular,

- `warnPartialMatchArgs`:
  logical. If true, warns if partial matching is used in argument matching.
- `warnPartialMatchAttr`:
  logical. If true, warns if partial matching is used in extracting attributes via attr.
- `warnPartialMatchDollar`:
  logical. If true, warns if partial matching is used for extraction by $.

Setting these variables will now raise warnings, that you can turn into errors if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Just arrived on another way to solve this, prompted by @Hemmo.

Use `sys.call()` to know how `myFunc` was called (with no partial argument matching, use `match.call` for that):

```
myFunc <- function(x, base='', ...) {
    x <- sys.call() # x[[1]] is myFunc, x[[2]] is x, ...
    argnames <- names(x)
    if (is.null(x$base)) {
        # if x[[3]] has no argname then it is the 'base' argument (positional)
        base <- ifelse(argnames[3] == '', x[[3]], '')
    }
    # (the rest of the `...` is also in x, perhaps I can filter it out by
    #  comparing argnames against names(formals(myFunc)) .

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late. But for future reference, I got this idea.

The partial matching can be avoided using quoted names. In a function, use sys.call() to the parameters.

```
    > myFunc <- function(x, base="base", ...) {
+     ## get the arguments
+     ss=sys.call()
+     
+     ## positional arguments can be retrieved using numbers
+     print(paste("ss[[2]]=",ss[[2]]))
+     
+     ## named arguments, no partial matching
+     print(ss[['base']]) ## NULL
+     
+     ## named arguments, no partial matching
+     print(ss[['b']]) ## "a"
+     
+     ## regular call, partially matched
+     print(base) ## "a"
+     
+     ## because 'b' is matched to 'base', 
+     ## 'b' does not exist, cause an error
+     print(b)
+ }
> 
> myFunc(x=1,b='a')
[1] "ss[[2]]= 1"
NULL
[1] "a"
[1] "a"
Error in print(b) : object 'b' not found
> myFunc(1,base="b")
[1] "ss[[2]]= 1"
[1] "b"
NULL
[1] "b"
Error in print(b) : object 'b' not found
> myFunc(2,"c")
[1] "ss[[2]]= 2"
NULL
NULL
[1] "c"
Error in print(b) : object 'b' not found
>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `sys.call()` to get access to function arguments as given by the caller. Care must be taken since `sys.call()` does not evaluate the arguments and instead gives you the *expression* of the call. This gets especially difficult when the function is called with `...` as an argument: The `sys.call()` will only contain the `...`, not their value. It is, however, possible to take the `sys.call()` and evaluate it as an argument list for another function, for example `list()`. This evaluates all promises and throws away some information, but I can't see how to get around this when trying to circumvent R's internal matching.

One idea would be to simulate strict matching. I appended a helper function that does exactly this if called as the first command in a function:

```
fun = function(x, base='', ...) {
  strictify()  # make matching strict

  list(x, base, ...)
}
```

This filters out nonmatching args:

```
> fun(10, b = 20)                                                                                                                                                                                   
[[1]]                                                                                                                                                                                               
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] ""

$b
[1] 20
```

and should also work in most other cases (with or without `...`, with arguments to the right of the `...`, with argument default values). The only thing it does not work with is non-standard evaluation, e.g. when trying to get the expression of an argument using `substitute(arg)`.

## The Helper Function

```
strictify <- function() {
  # remove argument values from the function
  # since matching already happened
  parenv <- parent.frame()  # environment of the calling function
  rm(list=ls(parenv), envir=parenv)  # clear that environment

  # get the arguments
  scall <- sys.call(-1)  # 'call' of the calling function
  callingfun <- scall[[1]]
  scall[[1]] <- quote(`list`)
  args <- eval.parent(scall, 2)  # 'args' is now a list with all arguments

  # if none of the argument are named, we need to set the
  # names() of args explicitly
  if (is.null(names(args))) {
    names(args) <- rep("", length(args))
  }

  # get the function header ('formals') of the calling function
  callfun.object <- eval.parent(callingfun, 2)
  callfun.header <- formals(callfun.object)
  # create a dummy function that just gives us a link to its environment.
  # We will use this environment to access the parameter values. We
  # are not using the parameter values directly, since the default
  # parameter evaluation of R is pretty complicated.
  # (Consider fun <- function(x=y, y=x) { x } -- fun(x=3) and
  # fun(y=3) both return 3)
  dummyfun <- call("function", callfun.header, quote(environment()))
  dummyfun <- eval(dummyfun, envir=environment(callfun.object))
  parnames <- names(callfun.header)

  # Sort out the parameters that didn't match anything
  argsplit <- split(args, names(args) %in% c("", parnames))
  matching.args <- c(list(), argsplit$`TRUE`)
  nonmatching.arg.names <- names(argsplit$`FALSE`)

  # collect all arguments that match something (or are just
  # positional) into 'parenv'. If this includes '...', it will
  # be overwritten later.
  source.env <- do.call(dummyfun, matching.args)
  for (varname in ls(source.env, all.names=TRUE)) {
    parenv[[varname]] <- source.env[[varname]]
  }

  if (!"..." %in% parnames) {
    # Check if some parameters did not match. It is possible to get
    # here if an argument only partially matches.
    if (length(nonmatching.arg.names)) {
      stop(sprintf("Nonmatching arguments: %s",
          paste(nonmatching.arg.names, collapse=", ")))
    }
  } else {
    # we manually collect all arguments that fall into '...'. This is
    # not trivial. First we look how many arguments before the '...'
    # were not matched by a named argument:
    open.args <- setdiff(parnames, names(args))
    taken.unnamed.args <- min(which(open.args == "...")) - 1
    # We throw all parameters that are unmatched into the '...', but we
    # remove the first `taken.unnamed.args` from this, since they go on
    # filling the unmatched parameters before the '...'.
    unmatched <- args[!names(args) %in% parnames]
    unmatched[which(names(unmatched) == "")[seq_len(taken.unnamed.args)]] <- NULL
    # we can just copy the '...' from a dummy environment that we create
    # here.
    dotsenv <- do.call(function(...) environment(), unmatched)
    parenv[["..."]] <- dotsenv[["..."]]
  }
}
```

It would also be possible to have a function that converts a normally matching function into a strictly matching function, e.g.

```
strict.fun = strictificate(fun)
```

but that would use the same kinds of tricks.

Answer (score -2):

this is a disgustingly horrible hack, but it might get the job done:

```
myFunc <- function(x, base='', b=NULL, ba=NULL, bas=NULL, ...) {
  dots <- list(b=b, ba=ba, bas=bas, ...)
  #..
}
```