# loop through rows to run meta analysis in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of summary statistics results [b/se/p] for different studies [different exposures]

## Create the sample dataframe

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Study = rep(c("Study 1", "Study 2", "Study 3", "Study 4", "Study 5"), each = 2),
  Stage = rep(c("Discovery", "Replication"), 5),
  b = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.3, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.4, 0.08, 0.15),
  se = c(0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.1, 0.12))
```

## Print the dataframe

```
print(dat)
```

I want to run a meta analysis for each pair of studies - so for 'study 1' or 'study 2', meta analysing the two sets of results - one result being Discovery and the other being Replication.

I have tried:

```
# Create an empty list to store the meta-analysis results
meta_results <- list()

# Perform meta-analysis for each stage (Discovery and Replication)
for (stage in c("Discovery", "Replication")) {
  # Filter the data for the current stage
  stage_data <- dat[dat$Stage == stage, ]
  
  # Run the meta-analysis using appropriate functions from the meta package
  meta_result <- meta::metagen(
    estimate = stage_data$b,
    se = stage_data$se,
    data = stage_data
  )
  
  # Store the meta-analysis result in the list
  meta_results[[stage]] <- meta_result
}

# Print the meta-analysis results
print(meta_results)
```

However I get the error

```
Error in meta::metagen(estimate = stage_data$b, se = stage_data$se, data = stage_data) : 
  argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments
```

So I don't think I am specifying correctly that there is a set of results for each stage for each study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also simplify by using `purrr`, e.g.

```
dat |> 
  split(dat$Study) |> 
  purrr::map(~meta::metagen(
    TE = b,
    seTE = se,
    data = .x
  ))
```

Comment: This is so cool, thanks! But I only get out a fixed and random effects model result, when I want a result for each study? The meta analysis result for discovery+replication? How do I get this?

Comment: You mean you want to have five models in total, one for each study? Change `split(dat$Stage)` to `split(dat$Study)`

Comment: Yes, if possible! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you check `?meta::metagen`, you'll see that there isn't a `estimate` and `se` arguments. The correct argument names are `TE` and `seTE`.

```
# Create an empty list to store the meta-analysis results
meta_results <- list()

# Perform meta-analysis for each stage (Discovery and Replication)
for (stage in c("Discovery", "Replication")) {
  # Filter the data for the current stage
  stage_data <- dat[dat$Stage == stage, ]
  
  # Run the meta-analysis using appropriate functions from the meta package
  meta_result <- meta::metagen(
    TE = Effect,
    seTE = Std_Error,
    data = stage_data
  )
  
  # Store the meta-analysis result in the list
  meta_results[[stage]] <- meta_result
}
```

**Result:**

```
$Discovery
Number of studies combined: k = 5

                                      95%-CI    z  p-value
Common effect model  0.1316 [0.0706; 0.1927] 4.23 < 0.0001
Random effects model 0.1321 [0.0661; 0.1981] 3.92 < 0.0001

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0.0007 [0.0000; 0.0447]; tau = 0.0260 [0.0000; 0.2113]
 I^2 = 9.5% [0.0%; 81.2%]; H = 1.05 [1.00; 2.30]

Test of heterogeneity:
    Q d.f. p-value
 4.42    4  0.3524

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- Restricted maximum-likelihood estimator for tau^2
- Q-Profile method for confidence interval of tau^2 and tau

$Replication
Number of studies combined: k = 5

                                      95%-CI    z  p-value
Common effect model  0.2167 [0.1527; 0.2807] 6.63 < 0.0001
Random effects model 0.2285 [0.1201; 0.3368] 4.13 < 0.0001

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0.0092 [0.0000; 0.1134]; tau = 0.0959 [0.0000; 0.3368]
 I^2 = 61.9% [0.0%; 85.7%]; H = 1.62 [1.00; 2.64]

Test of heterogeneity:
     Q d.f. p-value
 10.50    4  0.0327

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- Restricted maximum-likelihood estimator for tau^2
- Q-Profile method for confidence interval of tau^2 and tau
```

**Bonus: what does the error mean?**

R has partial matching for function parameters. That's why you can do `seq(1, by = 1, length = 10)`, even though `seq` doesn't have a `length` argument, only a `length.out` argument. R has matched the `length` to `length.out`. In your case, as R couldn't find a `se` argument, it tried matching, but found two possible matches for that word, and that's what the error means.

I recommend avoiding partial matching. Check this SO question: [Prevent partial argument matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264994/prevent-partial-argument-matching)

## Edit

Changing the order of the loop:

```
# Create an empty list to store the meta-analysis results
meta_results <- list()

# Perform meta-analysis for each stage (Discovery and Replication)
for (study in unique(dat$Study)) {
  # Filter the data for the current stage
  stage_data <- dat[dat$Study == study, ]
  
  # Run the meta-analysis using appropriate functions from the meta package
  meta_result <- meta::metagen(
    TE = Effect,
    seTE = Std_Error,
    data = stage_data
  )
  
  # Store the meta-analysis result in the list
  meta_results[[study]] <- meta_result
}

# Print the meta-analysis results
print(meta_results)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Its highly useful. However I think my question is confusing, I do not want the 5 studies meta anlaysed, I want, for each of the 5 studies, the meta analysed result of 'discovery' and 'replication'. Here we get two results [one for each fixed and random effects model] - do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You're welcome! I don't know if i understood, but check my edit